# Table row cannot appear as a child of a div component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do mapping in render method using Table but it gives error. When I run this component it do not show any output. I share my code below, please have a look in render method where i define table.

Thank you

```js
import  React from "react";
import DisplayCRMUser from "./DisplayCRMUser";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { contactReport_entities : []};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="table-responsive-xs cstm-configure-Content">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Topic</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.contactReport_entities.map ((val, index) => {
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{val.subject}</td>
                    <td>{val.createdon}</td>
                  </tr>
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>         
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not surround your `<tr>`-tags with a `<table>`-tag?

Comment: Can you add whole component file? Its bit confusion for now.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, hard yo help you. Looks like you are inserting the tr outside the table or tbody elements

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if you can see in the code I enclose the tr inside the table and tboday tag.

Comment: I don't think your code example is accurate.  You have two return statements.  Which one is correct?  Also, I think we may need to see the parent component being rendered depending on which return statement is correct.

Comment: Hi @MattHuggins, I edit my code. Please have a look again. Thanks in advance